# "link to document" content type hide

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a document library and there are 2 content types with it. Document and Link to document.I want to hide the "link to document" content type in word during the document save.

PS. I don't want to delete the content type because it is used by another custom action.

From word when i want to save the document to sharepoint its showing a dropdown to select the contenttyp which is "document" or "link to document". how can i hide this dropdown and make the word save a document as default.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you wan to hide the "Content type" drop-down list from new/Edit form?

To hide the "Content type" drop-down list from new/Edit form, add a content editor web part in the new/Edit form, add the following code in it:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("select[id*='ContentTypeChoice']").closest('tr').hide(); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: From word when i save the document to document library it shows the option to choose the contenttype, that i want to hide or make the word choose default contenttype.